# How to optimise the array calcuation using loops?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, refactoring

Hey i have array calculation where i need to refactor this code using loops please suggest...

```
<?php
arr = [286538,237034,192724,150815,117523,82754,49707];
$a1 = $arr[0]/7;
$a2 = ($a1+$arr[1])/7;
$a3 = ($a1+$a2+$arr[2])/7;
$a4 = ($a1+$a2+$a3+$arr[3])/7;
$a5 = ($a1+$a2+$a3+$a4+$arr[4])/7;
$a6 = ($a1+$a2+$a3+$a4+$a5+$arr[5])/7;
$a7 = ($a1+$a2+$a3+$a4+$a5+$a6+$arr[6])/7;
?>
```

```
Output -
40934
39709.714285714
39052.530612245
38644.463556851
39409.10120783
40071.972808949
41075.540353084
```

Comment: Can you post some sample code that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can utilize loops in your problem:

```
$arr = [286538,237034,192724,150815,117523,82754,49707];
$newArr = [];
$counter = 0;
while($counter < count($arr)){
  $sum = array_sum($newArr);
  $newArr[] = ($sum + $arr[$counter]) / 7;
  $counter++;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the support :) but i need to do this using for or while loop.

Comment: Did not notice that you need that. I've updated my answer accordingly. Let me know if this is what you want.

Comment: I already replaced it with `while` loop. If you still seeing `foreach` refresh your page to see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks man :) i have appreciated your efforts. @medz calculation is not correct while using the solution.

```
output is -
0] => 40934
    [1] => 39709.714285714 
    [2] => 33204.816326531 // instead of 39052.530612245 wrong value
    [3] => 26288.545189504 // 38644.463556851
    [4] => 20544.506455643 // 39409.10120783
    [5] => 14756.929493663 // 40071.972808949
    [6] => 9209.132784809 // 41075.540353084

```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$arr = [286538,237034,192724,150815,117523,82754,49707];

function calcarr($n){
    $result = 0;
    global $arr;
    if ($n <= 0) return $result;
    for ($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) $result += calcarr($i);
    return ($result + $arr[$n-1])/7;
}

$a1 = $arr[0]/7;
$a2 = ($a1+$arr[1])/7;
$a3 = ($a1+$a2+$arr[2])/7;
$a4 = ($a1+$a2+$a3+$arr[3])/7;
$a5 = ($a1+$a2+$a3+$a4+$arr[4])/7;
$a6 = ($a1+$a2+$a3+$a4+$a5+$arr[5])/7;
$a7 = ($a1+$a2+$a3+$a4+$a5+$a6+$arr[6])/7;

echo "$a7\n";
echo calcarr(7)."\n";
?>
```

RESULT:

```
41075.540353084
41075.540353084
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$arr = [286538,237034,192724,150815,117523,82754,49707];

$result = [];
foreach($arr as $k => $item)
    $result["a$k"] = (float) (array_sum($result) + $item)/7;

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(7) {
  ["a0"]=>
  float(40934)
  ["a1"]=>
  float(39709.714285714)
  ["a2"]=>
  float(39052.530612245)
  ["a3"]=>
  float(38644.463556851)
  ["a4"]=>
  float(39409.10120783)
  ["a5"]=>
  float(40071.972808949)
  ["a6"]=>
  float(41075.540353084)
}
```

If you want the variables as you have listed:

```
extract($result);
```

If you don't care about keys and to extract those variables, this will just give you a 0 indexed array as for your result:

```
foreach($arr as $item)
    $result[] = (float) (array_sum($result) + $item)/7;
```